# How do i install xcode on my ubuntu machine?

Tags: xcode, installation

I have Lenovo Ideapad310 laptop with Ubuntu OS. But for iOS development I want to install Xcode in my machine, so how can i install Xcode in my machine?
please anyone help me??

Answer (score 3):

First: You can't install Xcode on Ubuntu it's restricted only for Mac OS.

Second: I assume you want Swift, which you can install it over terminal using this command

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

If you installed the Swift toolchain on Linux to a directory other than the system root, you will need to run the following command, using the actual path of your Swift installation:

```
export PATH=/path/to/Swift/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

You can verify that you are running the expected version of Swift by entering the swift command and passing the --version flag:

```
swift --version
```

for IDE you might use Visual Studio Code and install Swift plugin.

Good Luck