# Missing function declaration for 'printout' CLIPS

Tags: c++, c, linux, clips

I have an executable file written in C++/MacOS takes a clips command and run it using `clips.h` functions. The executable works perfect on my Mac but once I try to run the same `clips` command I'm facing an error.

I've searched for any thing could help but I couldn't find a really helpful things.

The commands are simple and the functions should be builtin `clips` already.

here is the file I'm loading.

```
(defrule QPain
   =>
   (printout t "Are You In Pain? ") 
   (bind ?answer (read))
   (if (eq ?answer y)
      then
      (bind ?*symcount* (+ ?*symcount* 1))))
```

and here is my c++ code,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "clips.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Environment* env = NULL;
    env = CreateEnvironment();
    SetConserveMemory(env, true);
    ReleaseMem(env, 0);
    Load(env, "/path/to/clp/file/above");
    Reset(env);
    Run(env, -1);
return 0;
}
```

For the above code I'm facing theses two errors:

- `[EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for 'printout'.`

What I'm missing ? is there any libs I need to install on Linux for running such commands even I'm using `clips.h` functions ??

Comment: Readers won't be able to reconstruct your problem at home based on this description. You need to include the smallest set of code that people can copy/paste into their local computer and test against. Something like a "Hello World" program, but just the basics stuff for `clip`. Hard to believe `open()` is not found. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I've updated the question with code, would you please check it ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with MacOS stuff, so I was only offering the obvious help to get others to help you.I would also look at any that printout is using. I just did some research and it  seems there are special libs etc. Did you see this entry https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432497/620097 ? It looks promising to me. In general, getting software designed for one system architecture to run on a different sys arch can be anywhere from daunting to near impossible, so more research about cross-platform code will help you decide if this is worth the time. ,,,,

Comment: I would recommend adding a tag for the compiler you are using. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this for anyone who could struggle the same in future or could provide any help.

I was compiling clips with `gcc` compiler with the following flags:

`-O3 -g -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -DIO_FUNCTIONS=0 -c`

after going deeply through the Advance programming guide and each flag functionality I found a flag called `BASIC_IO` used to turn on/off the input/output functions (printout, open , .. , etc), so according to the guide I've changed the flag `DIO_FUNCTIONS = 1` and recompiled clips files so the problem was solved.

Note: the difference in flags names could be related to version of clips and compiler version.

thanks for every one who helped with this issue.

Comment: This flag is enabled by default, so unless you grabbed your source from a third party that's modified it you shouldn't have to change it.

Comment: that flags was set by another developer at the company I'm working at and he left, so no one knew what those flags used for since the names are different from the flag names in current clips version I'm referencing to. @GaryRiley